# Load numpy array of strings python 3

Tags: python, string, numpy

I am converting code from python 2 into python 3. The array was originally saved in python 2. As part of some of my code I load an array of strings that I have saved. In python 2, I can simply load it as

```
arr = np.load("path_to_string.npy")
```

and it gives me

```
arr = ['str1','str2' etc...]
```

however, when i do the same in python 3, it doesn't work and I get instead.

```
arr = [b'str1',b'str2' etc...]
```

which I take it means that the strings are stored as a different data type. I have tried to convert them using:

```
 arr = [str(i) for i in arr]
```

but this just compounds the problem. Can someone explain why this happens and how to fix it? I'm sure its trivial, but am just drawing a blank?

Comment: Since the file is saved using python2, you need  to use the 'encoding' parameter in np.load(). Read [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.load.html)

Comment: setting the encoding to any of their proposed values (bytes, ASCII or latin1) leads to the same issue. Setting fix_imports=True also doesn't help

Comment: you can do [i.decode() for  i in arr] too.

Comment: yes thanks this solves it!

Comment: @Vishal: `numpy`'s `astype` method will do the bulk conversion a bit faster, but yes, assuming the locale encoding is reasonable (or the text is pure ASCII and you're not on a truly weird locale), that will achieve the same result, producing a `list` rather than a new `numpy` array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be clear, if they were `str`s in Python 2, then `bytes` in Python 3 is the "correct" type, in the sense that both of them store byte data; if you wanted arbitrary text data, you would use `unicode` in Python 2.

For `numpy`, this is really the correct behavior; `numpy` doesn't want to silently convert from bytes-oriented data to text-oriented data (among other issues, doing so will bloat the memory usage by a factor of 4x, since fixed width representations of all Unicode characters use four bytes per character). If you really want to change from `bytes` to `str`, you can explicitly cast it, though it's a little bit hacky:

```
>>> arr  # Original version
array([[b'abc', b'123'],
       [b'foo', b'bar']], dtype='|S3')
>>> arr = arr.astype('U')  # Cast from "[S]tring" to "[U]nicode" equivalent
>>> arr
array([['abc', '123'],
       ['foo', 'bar']], dtype='<U3')
```

Comment: thanks! Makes sense that it stores it as bytes. A quick play with this also revealed that the slightly less verbose:
arr = np.load('path').astype('str') also works :)

Comment: @user3235916: Heh. As you were typing that, I found that `astype('U')` worked as well. `numpy` is being more helpful than I expected.